# How do I keep my Heroku deployed Django powered project DRY?

Tags: python, django, git, heroku, pip

I'm going to be hopefully deploying the first of many (fingers crossed!) projects through Heroku here soon. My concerns about a git and pip driven environment are that it becomes difficult to clone our internal reusable private Github repo apps through pip. For example, we have apps for blogs, comments, feedback, search, and so on that can be reused in other projects. What I have seen so far are that you can use either HTTP auth by embedding a username/password in the URL or jump through hoops generating an SSH key.

I appreciate you guys taking the time to read this. There are a million other things I'm sure you could be doing right now instead so thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend setting up a private PyPI server. I've been researching it recently, and the one that seemed best to me was [devpi](http://doc.devpi.net/latest/).

Alternatively, a paid-for service such as [Gemfury](http://www.gemfury.com/) may be more appropriate for you. I personally rejected it because it does not support releasing python packages the normal (`sdist upload`) way, but perhaps that was unfair.